# Conversion to ASCII

Tags: ascii, lexical-analysis

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<cstring>
#include<ctype.h>

using namespace std;

char *Data1[100];  
char *operators[20];
char *identifiers[20][20];
int ascii[100] = {0};
int ascii2[100] = {0};
unsigned int Tcount = 0;
unsigned int i;

int main(void)
{
    char *text = (char*)malloc ( 100 *sizeof( char));
    cout << "Enter the first arrangement of data." << endl;
    cin.getline(text, 100);
    char *token = strtok(text, " ");
    while ( token != NULL )
    {
        Data1[Tcount++] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");

    }
    for(i=0; i < Tcount; i++)
    {
        ascii[i] = (int)token[i];
        cout << ascii[i] << endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

The for loop at the bottom is supposed to store the 'tokens' ascii values in an array. When i enter user input to the tokeniser as "x = a + 1, " The program is terminated without printing out any ASCII values.
Any help with this would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the role of the following section?

```
char *token = strtok(text, " ");
while ( token != NULL )
{
    Data1[Tcount++] = token;
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");

}
```

It counts the number of "tokens"?
But when you assign ascii[i], you take the first number_of_tokens characters of text?

Comment: You're right, sorry i have forgotten to update the program, i will edit the post now

Comment: Im relatively new to C++, is there any chance you could tell me how i can use the the 'token' in the for loop instead of 'text'

Comment: It depends what are your assumptions and goals.
Do you assume each token has a single character?
Do you want to print all character's ASCIIs excluding backspaces?

Comment: I dont want to assume all tokens are single characters, i want to separate them with blankspace as a delimitor. I dont want to print the ASCII values of the blankspace. for example if my input is;
X = A + 1
i want the ASCII return to exclude blankspace.
There will be a problem when i enter in user input in the form;
X = AB + C 
due to there being no space between A and B but i will try to solve that later.

Comment: never mind, im sorted now, thanks for the help anyway

Comment: @user4878925You should "accept" the answer, otherwise the question will remain in the unanswered question queue....